# Logitech Solar Keyboard K750 Only Works in USB 2.0 but not in USB 3.0

Tags: usb, logitech

So the title is pretty straightforward, I have the Logitech K750 Solar Keyboard, and it literally will not function at all when I plug the usb receiver into a usb 3.0 port, but works great when I plug it into a usb 2.0 port.  It's not a huge deal, but I'd like to put the receiver into a usb port in the back of my computer to free up my usb ports in the front and there aren't any usb 2.0 ports back there.

I have checked the usb 3.0 ports with a flash drive I have, and they worked, so I don't believe it's a problem with the usb ports, but maybe I need drivers?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and the more specific the details the better as I've only had a stable version of Linux for about 2 days.  (getting the nvidia drivers to work correctly was a real pain!)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link helps :)

http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38032/section/troubleshoot/crid/404/lt_product_id/7454/tabs/1,3,2,4,5/cl/us,en

Have Fun !

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately that's not what's happening.  The only wireless usb device I have connected is the logitech unifying receiver, so it's not a matter of interference from a different wireless usb plug in.  My usb mouse is plugged into the back of the computer through a usb 3.0 port, so it's also not that my usb 3.0 ports aren't working, because they work for everything else.  The logitech receiver is the only thing that doesn't function in the usb 3.0 port.