# Logitech M570 Not Detected

Tags: mouse, logitech, logitech-unifying

My Logitech M570 mouse doesn't seem to be recognised in Ubuntu 12.04.

It has worked the first time I plugged it in, and then only once since then when I unplugged the usb dongle and tried again. That seems to have been a 'one-off' victory.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Beginner's instructions greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: In the source I linked someone claims it is plug and play... weird. If my answer does not work please leave a comment and I'll remove it.

Comment: @Rinzwind This question is not about [pairing](http://askubuntu.com/a/114089/6969) but about losing connection. Try using a different USB port and/ remove any possible objects that may interfere with the wireless receiver and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all other mice. install the dongle on one of the back usb ports.

I couldn't get my M570 to work until I did that..once I did it just started working.