# How to overcome this error while compiling RT2870 driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers, compiling

I bought a rather cheap wifi antenna and now have to install RT2870 driver on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

I downloaded driver file 2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1 from its official web page and tried to compile it, but I get compile error which I do not know how to overcome.

So after I issue `make` the process starts and after some time it ends with

```
/home/xxx/Desktop/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOSNetDevDetach’:
/home/xxx/Desktop/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1694:38: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
  struct net_device_ops *pNetDevOps = pNetDev->netdev_ops;
                                      ^
/home/xxx/Desktop/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOSNetDevAttach’:
/home/xxx/Desktop/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1731:38: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
  struct net_device_ops *pNetDevOps = pNetDev->netdev_ops;
                                      ^
make[2]: *** [/home/xxx/Desktop/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/xxx/Desktop/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Is the error in the lines I posted or I need to post the complete make log?

If this is enough, what is the error and how to fix it?

Let me know if you need more info.

**EDIT**

The result of `lsusb` is

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 021: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I plan to connect the antenna to USB 3 port, but any other 2.0 port would be fine.

The antenna is so called "long range" and is attached to a USB wireless adapter via coax cable, while USB cable comes from adapter to the PC.

It looks like this

[image]

When I try to see the `dmesg` response with plug in/plug out, I get this response:

```
USB 3.0 port
Dec  4 18:04:54 lmachine kernel: [10849.357767] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
Dec  4 18:04:54 lmachine kernel: [10849.357997] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:04:54 lmachine kernel: [10849.561776] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:04:54 lmachine kernel: [10849.765513] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 42, error -71
Dec  4 18:04:54 lmachine kernel: [10849.877506] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 43 using xhci_hcd
Dec  4 18:04:54 lmachine kernel: [10849.877740] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:04:55 lmachine kernel: [10850.081491] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:04:55 lmachine kernel: [10850.285161] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 43, error -71
Dec  4 18:04:55 lmachine kernel: [10850.397118] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
Dec  4 18:04:55 lmachine kernel: [10850.397317] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:04:55 lmachine kernel: [10850.601210] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:04:55 lmachine kernel: [10850.804880] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 44, error -71
Dec  4 18:04:55 lmachine kernel: [10850.916809] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
Dec  4 18:04:55 lmachine kernel: [10850.916998] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:04:56 lmachine kernel: [10851.120847] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:04:56 lmachine kernel: [10851.324533] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 45, error -71
Dec  4 18:04:56 lmachine kernel: [10851.324563] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2

USB 2.0 port
Dec  4 18:08:03 lmachine kernel: [11038.030811] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
Dec  4 18:08:03 lmachine kernel: [11038.031007] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:08:03 lmachine kernel: [11038.234943] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:08:03 lmachine kernel: [11038.438574] usb 3-4: device not accepting address 46, error -71
Dec  4 18:08:03 lmachine kernel: [11038.550577] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 47 using xhci_hcd
Dec  4 18:08:03 lmachine kernel: [11038.550849] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:08:03 lmachine kernel: [11038.754561] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:08:04 lmachine kernel: [11038.958250] usb 3-4: device not accepting address 47, error -71
Dec  4 18:08:04 lmachine kernel: [11039.070209] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
Dec  4 18:08:04 lmachine kernel: [11039.070405] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:08:04 lmachine kernel: [11039.274254] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:08:04 lmachine kernel: [11039.477961] usb 3-4: device not accepting address 48, error -71
Dec  4 18:08:04 lmachine kernel: [11039.589985] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 49 using xhci_hcd
Dec  4 18:08:04 lmachine kernel: [11039.590238] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:08:04 lmachine kernel: [11039.793950] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address.
Dec  4 18:08:05 lmachine kernel: [11039.997635] usb 3-4: device not accepting address 49, error -71
Dec  4 18:08:05 lmachine kernel: [11039.997665] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old driver, circa 2010, was built for 2.6.xx kernels; as you can see, you are running 3.13.0-39. It will never compile.

The driver for these devices, rt2800usb, is included in Ubuntu 14.04 by default. If it isn't working as expected, something else is wrong. 
Please tell us what is wrong and details about your device:

```
lsusb
```

I assume your USB wireless is attached to this:

```
046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

Googling, I found this: [Is Logitech's Unifying receiver supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113984/is-logitechs-unifying-receiver-supported) I suggest you install *ltunify* and see if the wireless appears.

Comment: I edited the question with new data. Let me know should you need anything else. PS. I totally forgot about 3x kernel. Have been using Linux for 10+ years and in my mind I am still on 2.6 kernel.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Actually I noticed that Ubuntu did not recognize it thou it was plugged in. So it's neither of devices you can see in the list. For example, it was on USB 3.0 port and it does not say anything. I have attached the image above

Comment: Is there any message here as you plug in the device? tail -f /var/log/syslog

Comment: I posted messages for both usb 3.0 and 2.0 ports

Comment: Based on the messages you posted and since they appear when plugged in to different USB ports, I wonder if the device is defective. Does it work or at least appear when plugged in to other computers?

Comment: I have to check this. I will ask my colleague to check if the device work using his multimeter.

Comment: A multimeter will just tell you if the device is open circuit or not. I highly suggest you insert it in any other computer and see if it is recognized as a wireless device.

Comment: I tried on another machine, Win 8, and nothing happened. I have no other Linux machine at disposal. I will replace the device and then check again with your suggestions. Thanks