# Is it possible to manage (pair) Logitech Unifying devices in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: ppa, 15.10, logitech, logitech-unifying

Unfortunately, project Solaar is discontinued and there is no PPA or package available for Ubuntu 15.10.

Both these repositories are old and do not support a version for Wiley:

https://launchpad.net/~daniel.pavel/+archive/ubuntu/solaar
https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/ubuntu/solaar

I am surprised Logitech does not provide a tool for linux :(

Does anyone know how to make Solaar work in the newest Ubuntu version?

There is a [Github project](https://github.com/pwr/Solaar), but does anyone know how to build Solaar from the source? Or is there an alternative to Solaar ?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: the ppa is no longer needed, see my answer for more

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/258966/65969) answer to the original question about solaar, there is no longer a need for a ppa as `solaar` is now included in the Ubuntu "universe" repositories.

If you already have the "universe" enabled then you can install it via the Software Center by searching by it for name.

If you do no have it enabled there are a couple of ways to do that.

1. Use the Software Center to search for `solaar`. It should find it but tell you that is is avialble tru the "universe" repos and where the install button should be will be a button to "Use Source" click this and the rest should happen automatically.
2. If searching in the Software Center does not work, or you wish to do it yourself, you can do this with `Software and Updates`.  Search for it using the dash, click on it and you will get window like this
   [image]

The second box down needs to be checked to allow universe sources.  Check the box, enter your password in the box that pops up.  This will enable the source.  When you close the Software and Updates window, it will ask you if you want to reload you software sources.

Answer **Yes** and your software sources will update, you will then be able to find and install solaar in the software center.

**Note:** If you want the indicator and better integration with Unity(or Gnome shell), look in the "optional add ons" section on the More info" page of the software Center.  You will want to click on(or make sure it is already selected) the "solaar gmone3" addon or you will only have the terminal version of solaar.

---

You can also install via the terminal by `sudo apt-get install solaar-gnome3`

This will install the packages needed to integrate with Unity and Gnome DE and will pull in and install `solaar` as well.
If you only want the command line of solaar, you can get that by `sudo apt-get install solaar`.

Comment: I had not even checked in the official Ubuntu repository...Indeed it is there and it works flawlessly! No need for a PPA! Thank you very much !!

Comment: I have universe enabled and still can't find it in the app centre. Doesn't work via the terminal either:

:~$ sudo apt-get install solaar-gnome3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package solaar-gnome3

Comment: @user240891 you need to run `sudo apt-get update` after enabling or adding new repository.  I just checked using 16.10 and found it so it's there.  If you are using the 17.04 beta, it is likely that the repos for it are still a bit bare and it's not in the beta repos yet.

Comment: How do you actually use/configure solaar once it had been installed by apt?!!