# Dell bluetooth keyboard stops working for a couple of seconds on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and Bluetooth keyboard Dell WK717, the problem is that it stops working from time to time. It happens when the keyboard is idle for some short amount of time, it doesn't type immediately after I press a button but it requires me to press several times a button to make it work again.
I had a similar problem with the Dell mouse but than I've got a logitech one and this problem doesn't occur any longer.

UPD the problem persists also with dells' universal usb
UPD2 The problem is due to low charge of batteries.However, keyboard didn't signal low charge.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal do

```
echo "options btusb enable_autosuspend=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/btusb.conf
```

Reboot and see if disabling autosuspend fixes the issue

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately the behavior didn't change. One thing also -- rarely I see repeating characters pressed without me touching the keyboard. With mac the same keyboard worked fine

Comment: I've tried with dell's paring usb and the problem persists

Comment: Maybe it is just weak batteries, changed and investigating. On mac when the battery were low in power, keyboard just stopped working.

Comment: looks like new batteries have solved the problem, although keyboard didn't complain about low power.