# Can't connect my mx master to the unifying receiver (14.04 LTS)

Tags: mouse, logitech

Used to work just fine. But I set something else on channel 2 and proceeded to pair it with the PC on channel 1. Well it seems to not be possible anymore.
I followed the tutorial (power on mouse, select chan, press connect, plug-in receiver) lots of times. Can't get it to connect. It just keeps rapidly blinking.

I even tried shutting off all bluetooth devices in the house just in case they are confusing it.
The ubuntu solaar software that mimics the logitech software seems to be discontinued.

So, what else to try here?

Please note that it used to work, I just can't pair it again.

Comment: I had the same problem, albeit in 16.04. This solved it:
https://askubuntu.com/a/258966/741666

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comment, try out [Solaar](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/):

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install solaar`

Once you run it, you can manage the pairing of your MX Master.

I had a similar problem; I think I overwrote the channel that was paired with the receiver. I cleared up the pairing with Solaar and then paired the mouse again: works like a charm.

Comment: +1 for Solaar. I was trying to reset my mouse settings for half an hour after accidentally pairing to my Mac on the same channel, and absolutely nothing would fix it. Installed Solaar and clicked the "unpair" button and everything started working again just like that.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 21.10 with MX Master => works perfectly !

Comment: Installed solaar, disconnected the connection and reconnected with the mouse and keyboard. Now it works like a charm