# Logitech mouse freezing ubuntu 18

Tags: usb, 18.04, mouse, freeze, logitech

Logitech M170 mouse some times hard freezing and lag for 5-7 seconds.
I'm try to disable power saving for usb devices, but it don't help.

```
sudo powernap-action --disable usb_autosuspend
```

and

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend >/dev/null
```

In dmesg always after freez

```
[ 6591.387398] perf: interrupt took too long (2502 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[ 9650.687098] perf: interrupt took too long (3283 > 3127), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 60750
[18608.931249] perf: interrupt took too long (4145 > 4103), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 48250
```

Maybe this is not related, but always a similar message.

Laptop: Lenovo-ideapad 320

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's your USB ports or the USB hub which is trying to auto-suspend due to power management.

What's the output of

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/control
```

what message do you get now and do you still get the same if you run this after booting the machine?

```
echo "on" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/control
```

If it is not persistent between machine reboots.

You can also check with powertop if you prefer something slightly more user friendly.

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

Look on the tunables tab. If it's set to bad then auto-suspend is disabled and this is what you want. Try and let us know?

Comment: `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/control
auto
auto`
`echo "on" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/control
on`
powertop say  `Bad Autosuspend USB USB Receiver [Logitech]` Autosuspend is turned off. After reboot settings save

Comment: is there a tiny button or a hole to do a factory reset on your Logitech M170 wireless mouse and see if it helps?

Comment: No, no any buttons. At Windows 10 on same laptop everything ok. On PC under windows mouse work fine.

Comment: Shame Logitech hasn't added any SW utility for Linux. Only windows :(

Comment: If you really want to debug try -
`grep -i mouse /var/log/dmesg`
`dmesg | grep Logitech:`

If you want to 
Having that said, Logitech only supports Unifying software for Windows and Mac OS X. For Linux, theres a link to Reverse Engineering and unpairing tool. Quick installation installations if you really want to make it work:

[link] https://askubuntu.com/questions/113984/is-logitechs-unifying-receiver-supported

`sudo apt-get install git gcc`
`git clone https://git.lekensteyn.nl/ltunify.git`
`cd ltunify`
`make install-home`

Comment: `dmesg | grep Logitech`
`[    1.83] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.42] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:046D:C534.0001/input/input5
[    2.48] hid-generic 0003:046D:C534.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[    2.48] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0002/input/input6
[    2.54] hid-generic 0003:046D:C534.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1`

Comment: Try to install this and see if it works? 
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install solaar

Comment: It looks strange, but when the charging cable is disconnected, the mouse stops freezing. When connect charger it start again. It looks like a hardware problem, may be bad shielded input power filters. I'll try to use a USB hub and watch. OR HDMI connector. When work from battery without HDMI monitor everything good... But on windows work fine on same laptop same charger same monitor...

Comment: it is definitely strange behaviour, it might be a hardware issue than a software one if you have tried everything. You are also eliminating all the possibilities so it works fine on Windows but not on Ubuntu upon connecting the charging cable?