# Does Touch Mouse Logitech M600 works on  Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use the Logitech Touch Mouse M600?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110306/can-i-use-the-logitech-touch-mouse-m600)

I am interested in the purchase of Touch Mouse "Logitech Mouse M600" and wanted to know how it works in Ubuntu 12.04.